# ES6 method is not defined in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class, create-react-app

I'm having difficulty understanding why `create-react-app` is unable to compile, telling me that `error  'updateWord' is not defined  no-undef`.  I'm fairly new to React with ES6.  Normally I would write a component like `const App = React.createClass({ });` but I've decided to try out some syntactical sugar instead.

I have parent component `App` and a child component `Input`:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // all other code omitted...
  }

  handleInput(input) {
    console.log(`handle: ${input}`); 
    updateWord(input);
    // this also causes an error
    // this.updateWord(input);
  }

  updateWord(input) {
    console.log(`update ${input}`);
    // why isn't this defined?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Input onInput={this.handleInput} />
      </div>
      );
  }
}

class Input extends Component {
  handleInput(e) {
    let input = e.target.value;
    this.props.onInput(input);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)} />
      </form>
      );
  }
}
```

I've tried changing to `this.updateWord(input);` instead of `updateWord(input)` but to no avail. I get:

```
"App.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: this.updateWord is not a function"
```

Normally when I implement a similar pattern (with ES5) to what I'm doing now I have no difficulties.  For example:

```
const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    // all other code omitted...
  },

  handleInput: function(input) {
    console.log(`handle: ${input}`); 
    this.updateWord(input);
  },

  updateWord: function(input) {
    console.log(`update ${input}`);
    // In theory, this implementation would not cause any errors?
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Input onInput={this.handleInput} />
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, still having an issues.  I changed my method to `updateWord` and when I try to invoke the method as `updateWord(input)` I still get "error  'updateWord' is not defined  no-undef" if I try to call it as `this.updateWord(input)` I get the error "App.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: this.updateWord is not a function" @AndrewLi  My apologies, I'll update my question now....

Comment: No, I think there was a misunderstanding on both parties :( I jumped the gun thinking your suggestion solved my problem.  I still have this issue when renaming the update method. @AndrewLi

Comment: No problem @AndrewLi

Comment: @AndrewLi yes, I still get "App.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: this.updateWord is not a function"

Comment: I think I've got it. Use `this.updateWord` and then change `onInput` to `{this.handleInput.bind(this)}`.

Comment: @AndrewLi That appears to have worked :) Thanks!  Can you write a detailed answer for me so I can understand why and I will gladly upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `this.updateWord(...)` in `this.handleInput`, `this` refers to the `Input` component. Let me illustrate the problem:

When you set the `onInput` handler, like so:

```
onInput={this.handleInput}
```

Here, since your `Input` component is calling the function, `this` refers to the `Input` component. This is due to the line:

```
this.props.onInput(input);
```

The `Input` component is calling `handleInput`. That means, in your `handleInput` function, the `this` context is `Input`. Consider the line:

```
this.updateWord(input);
```

in the `handleInput` function. Here you call `this.updateWord`, but since `this` is `Input`, it tries to call `updateWord` from `Input` which does not exist, thus throwing the error.

---

The solution is to explicitly bind the `this` context *as the class (`App` component)* instead of the `Input` component, using either [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). From the documentation:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value

You can apply it like so:

```
onInput={this.handleInput.bind(this)}
```

Or more preferably in the constructor:

```
this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
```

With the second option you may then do:

```
onInput={this.handleInput}
```

(This is more preferable as binding in the `render` method will create a new function every time on render, which isn't preferred).

The `this` context in the line above is the class. Since you bind `this`, the *class* will be correctly used as `this` context in the function and executing `this.updateWord` will invoke the method in the *class*.

An even more preferable way is to use arrow functions instead of regular ES6 methods. From the documentation:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and does not bind its own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`.

We can apply this by assigning `handleInput` to an arrow function instead of a regular method:

```
handleInput = (input) => {
    console.log(`handle: ${input}`); 
    this.updateWord(input);
}
```

This will eliminate the use of `bind` completely and instead, use arrow functions. Since arrow functions don't bind their own `this`, it means `this` refers to the enclosing context. In the example above, a method is not used thus `this` refers to the class (the enclosing context). That will correctly call the class method `updateWord`, and consequently, you need not change the `onInput` event handler if you go this route.